# How to find the same entries in 2 pandas series but with different case sensitivity

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to compare 2 pandas series and find the same entries in both series but with different case sensitivity.

Similary to the below example:

```
 df['Comment']=np.where((df['Identifier_1']==df['Identifier_2']),'The same',df['Comment'])
```

but condition should be somehow changed so that if Identifier_1='aBc' and Identifier_2='Abc' then returns True.

Thanx and BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Identifier_1':['aBc','aBC'],
                   'Identifier_2':['Abc','ABZ'],
                   'Comment':['com1','com2']})

df['Comment']=np.where(df['Identifier_1'].str.lower() == df['Identifier_2'].str.lower(),
                       'The same',
                        df['Comment'])

print (df)
  Identifier_1 Identifier_2   Comment
0          aBc          Abc  The same
1          aBC          ABZ      com2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lower()`:

```
df['Comment']=np.where(df['Identifier_1'].astype(str).lower() == df['Identifier_2'].astype(str).lower(),'The same',df['Comment'])
```

This will default both strings to lowercase so they can be compared as you requiered. This way `AbC` and `aBc` will be turned into `abc` and `abc` respectively, returning `True`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `str.lower()` to make them both lowercase.

```
df['Comment']=np.where(df['Identifier_1'].str.lower().equals(df['Identifier_2'].str.lower()),
                      'The same',
                      df['Comment'])
```